# MageStackDay Feb 2015 recap

Tags: discussion

**91 developers, from 26 nationalities answering 563 questions, earning 311 badges getting the acceptance rate up from 71.74% to 74.78% (+3.04%)!**

In 2 days we've accomplished so much and as a bonus we had a great time doing it. So, some stats measured between 13 feb 07:00 - 15 feb 21:30.

- *Badges earned*: 311
- *Votes spent*: 1140
- *Comments added*: 629
- *Answers added*: 458
- *Number of unanswered questions*: -563
- *Answers that got accepted*: 75
- *New questions*: 80
- *New users*: 12

**Fact & funfacts about MageStackDay #2**

- 91 participants signed up, including 5 female developers!
- 9 companies supporting the community answering questions on MageStackDay
- 2 bounty-hunt questions about Magento 2: The questions will stay open till Friday 20th of February and the bounty will be awarded to the best answer which will be chosen by Anton.
- 1 new website running on HHVM
- 1 [opening firework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTHRV.jpg)
- 1 [new gist](https://gist.github.com/avoelkl/0f26bd2c9ee85862e820) with a collection of stackexchange-queries
- 0 lines of CSS touched by Sander and Anna during the creation of the new website
- Some requests about together.js, pair answering and spoonprogramming in the #speeddating channel, no one successful (as far as we know)

And there was so much more going on: new extensions got created during this time (we call it SDD - StackExchange Driven Develoment), some of our participants signed up and answered their first questions on the site and a lot of them decided to become regularly active!

**And from here**

We hope to see you back on a regular basis to answer, upvote and flag questions. Together we can make this a great place to gain and share knowledge on Magento

Comment: what about animal stats?

Comment: Well I have 2 rats again, Anna is on the cats... not sure about the rest. Good one!

Comment: We had 3 people who posted their MageStackDay survival package. Need to collect more fun stats next time again!

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, but what's the question?

Closing.

(j/k kick-ass job!)

Comment: This does not answer the question and so should be deleted ;)